# I am struggling to import a .csv file in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am just getting started with Visual C++ and trying to import data from a .csv file in a a string array. I'm aware that this question has been asked by others but my problem is that my program is not even reading the file at the location. I tried following the leads from codes on this website but to no avail. I'm sure it's a silly issue but am a new starter with the language. Code and the output is given below. What do you think is the issue?. If you guys require the csv file, please let me know and I will be willing to forward you on your email.:

// New_work.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
  #include "stdafx.h" 

   #include <iostream>

   #include <string>

   #include <fstream>

   using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i, j;

    string VolsCorrs[50][20];

    ifstream reader;
    reader.open("C:\C++_Programs\EaR_20130719_VolsCorrs_V5.csv");

    if (!reader)
    {
        cout << "Error opening input file" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<22; j++)
        {
            getline(reader, VolsCorrs[i][j], ',');
        }
    }

    reader.close();

    cout << "Volatility and Correlation input" << VolsCorrs << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
'New_work.exe': Loaded 'C:\C++_Programs\New_work\Debug\New_work.exe', Symbols loaded.
'New_work.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'New_work.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'New_work.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'New_work.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'New_work.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The program '[15844] New_work.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: You need to double up ``\`` characters in strings, or they will be treated as escapes.

Comment: Many thanks. This certainly seems to be a problem.

Comment: `/` instead of `\\` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, one issue is that your array is of dimension 50x20 and in your nested for loop you're accessing index [i][20] and [i][21] because of the `j<22` condition. These are outside the array's boundaries and thus result in a memory violation.